branch analyze using Jenkins
I know ther is branch analyzing in SonarQube
Is ther similar thing in Jenkins? or any way to analyze branches using Jenkins?
I looked it up documents from Jenkins and there was multibranch pipeline concept but I couldn't find the way to analyze branches

Follow SonarQube documentation for that: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/jenkins-extension-sonarqube/
